# power-shell birthday HTML

Tags: powershell

I am writing  a script for “My Birthday is *** days away!” countdown and convert it to HTML as MyBirthday.html.

Idid this so far

```
 function Date {
$Name = Read-Host "Please enter your name"
$BirthMonth = Read-Host "Please enter your Month of Birthday"
$BirthDay = Read-Host "Please enter your Day of Birthday"
$BirthYear = (Get-Date).Year

$NumberOfDays=(New-TimeSpan -End "$BirthYear/$BirthMonth/$BirthDay").Days

if ($NumberOfDays -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "Happy Birthday $Name. Today is your Birthday! Yeah!"
} 
else {
    Write-Host "Hello $Name, there are $NumberOfDays days to your Birthday!"
}
}

Out-File Date > C:\Users\Desktop\Date.html
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is how to out put this scrip as there are number of days for birthday not  like -33  and also how to convert this to HTML

Comment: Well, to avoid negative days there are a couple of solutions. One is to see if the birthday this year is less than now. If it is, get the number of days until the birthday next year. As for getting HTML, in powershell type: `Get-Command ConvertTo-Html`

Comment: Could you show me how to do it ?

Comment: Presumably you are doing this to learn powershell. In which case I have given you a direction to go. Please attempt to figure this out and write some code then update your question to explain the problems that you are having with that code. I will suggest this also: `Get-Help Get-Date`

Comment: is it correct now the convert and out file

Comment: Since yoou are using Write-Host, I would not expect that to output anything. Did you test it?

Comment: @EBGreen I doubt it's been tested in any way other than by using Write-EBGreen so far.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to keep everything as an object (in this case a DateTime object) as it's much easier to manipulate.

I would do it as follows - I've annotated with comments, but if you have any questions ask.

```
function Date ($Name,$BirthMonth,$BirthDay)
{
    #Create a datetime object
    $Date = Get-Date -day $BirthDay -month $BirthMonth -year ((Get-Date).Year)    

    #Check if the entered date is before today
    if($Date -lt (Get-Date))
    {
        #If so add 1 year
        $Date = $Date.AddYears(1)
    }
    $NumberOfDays = New-Timespan -Start (Get-Date) -End $date

    if ($NumberOfDays.Days -eq 0) 
    {
        $result = "Happy Birthday $Name. Today is your Birthday! Yeah!"
    } 
    else
    {
        $result = "Hello $Name, there are $($NumberOfDays.Days) days to your Birthday!"
    }

    #Create an object to return (Objects are easier and more flexible to work with down the pipeline)
    $return = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        'Days Remaining' = $result
    }

    #Return the object
    $return


}

#User input outside of the function (makes the function re-usable)
$Name = Read-Host "Please enter your name"
$BirthMonth = Read-Host "Please enter your Month of Birthday"
$BirthDay = Read-Host "Please enter your Day of Birthday"

#Call the function, pass the input and pipe the output
Date $Name $BirthMonth $BirthDay | ConvertTo-HTML > C:\users\jacob\desktop\date.html

#Demonstration of the returned object
Date $Name $BirthMonth $BirthDay
```